# If a function is created within a function, does it get created again every time the outer one is called?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'd like to know if creating a function within a function (or within a loop, for that matter) would make the nested one get created over and over again. Mostly for efficiency reasons.

[Some preliminary search](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/) tells me that a nested function will continue to be referenced while the outer function remains. So... I assume it wouldn't be created again? I'm not sure.

There's three flavors of functions,

```
function bar() {};
let bar = function() {};
let bar = () => {};
```

And two use cases:

Nested inside `foo()` (which only ever gets defined once)

```
function foo() { /*declare bar in here*/ }

for(/*a bazillion times*/)
    foo();
```

Declared naked in the loop:

```
for(/*a bazillion times*/) {
    /*declare bar in here*/
}
```

So what's standard, and what can be expected?

And before you answer, yes, I know I risk losing my webdeveloper license for asking about performance. ;)

Comment: *nested one get created over and over again* **Yes.**

Comment: To give more context on my previous comment, a function call creates a local scope. Then creates local variable inside this scope. On end, the scope is destroyed and variables are left strayed(*except closure*). They are then captured by garbage collector and removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the function without saving it in a variable (1. flavor) then defining it inside the loop *could* be faster. The reason is that if you never enter the loop the function object will never be constructed.

Also the function object is not constructed again each time you enter the loop. At least this is the case in Chromium and Firefox. I don't know what the spec says.

I used this code to test it:

```js
var f = null;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    function bar()
    {
        if (f == null)
            f = this;
        else if (f == this)
            document.getElementById("moh").textContent += "same function, ";
        else
            document.getElementById("moh").textContent += "diff function, ";
    };
    bar();
}
```

```html
<div id="moh"></div>
```

Also interesting is that you can call bar() from outside the loop. But only if the loop was executed once.